# I use shiny dashboard sidebar and get mongolite error

Tags: r, shiny, mongolite

I have an error "Error in mongo_collection_new: is.character(db) not TRUE" when I use siderbarMenuOutput (client side) and renderMenu (server side).

App is very big, that include mongolite.

If I use standard structure:

client:

```
sidebarMenu(
            menuItem('1', tabName = 'tab1'),
            menuItem('2', tabName = 'tab2'),
            menuItem('3', tabName = 'tab3'))
```

an error is not, but if I change it

client:

```
siderbarMenuOutput('menu')
```

server:

```
output$menu <- renderMenu({
    lapply(c('1','2','3'), function(x) {
        menuItem(x, tabName = paste0('item_',x)
    })
})
```

an error appears.

I tried this example too
[Create shiny dashboard sidebar menu from dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56361770/create-shiny-dashboard-sidebar-menu-from-dataframe)

but I still get this same error

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your ui changes trigger connection to mongo:

The error means you passed wrong value to `mongo(collection = value)`
Pass an existing table name as a character and it should work fine.

```
mongo_connection <- mongo(
            collection = "collection_name",
            db = "dbname",
            url = "mongodb+srv://yoururlstring",
            options = ssl_options()
)
```